# Laravel logout after do a store function

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel logout and not store data to database after do a store function where it supposed to be redirecting to backend page **here's the form :**

```
div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
              <h3 class="font-weight-bold" style="margin-left: 510px;">Tambah Post Art Movement</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{route('blogstore')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputName1">Nama Art Movement</label>
                  <input type="text" value="{{ old('nama_art') }}" class="form-control @error('nama_art') is-invalid @enderror" name="nama_art" id="nama" placeholder="Nama Art Movement">
                  @error('nama_art')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Foto Art Movement</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control @error('foto_art') is-invalid @enderror" name="foto_art">
                  <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                  </div>
                  @error('foto_art')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="example1">Tahun awal dikenal</label>
                  <input type="text" name="tahun_awal" value="{{ old('tahun_awal') }}" class="form-control @error('tahun_awal') is-invalid @enderror" id="example1" placeholder="Tahun awal dikenal">
                  @error('tahun_awal')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="example2">Tahun akhir dikenal</label>
                  <input type="text" name="tahun_akhir" value="{{ old('tahun_akhir') }}" class="form-control @error('tahun_akhir') is-invalid @enderror" id="example2" placeholder="Tahun akhir dikenal">
                  @error('tahun_akhir')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleTextarea">Deskripsi</label>
                  <textarea  name="deskripsi_art" class="form-control @error('deskripsi_art') is-invalid @enderror" name="content" rows="5" id="deskripsi" placeholder="Masukkan Deskripsi Postingan">{{ old('content') }}</textarea>
                  @error('deskripsi_art')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="tautan">Tautan</label>
                  <input type="text" name="tautan_art" value="{{ old('tautan_art') }}" class="form-control @error('tautan_art') is-invalid @enderror" id="tautan" placeholder="Tautan">
                  @error('tautan_art')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="nama_tautan">Nama Tautan</label>
                    <select class="form-control @error('nama_tautan_art') is-invalid @enderror" id="nama_tautan_art" name="nama_tautan_art">
                      <option>Wikipedia</option>
                      <option>© Grove Art / OUP</option>
                    </select>
                    @error('nama_tautan_art')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                      {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                  @enderror
                  </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Simpan</button>
              </form>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
              <script>
                  CKEDITOR.replace( 'deskripsi_art' );
              </script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**heres the controller** where is supposed to get a value from the form and store it to database and redirect to backend page but instead it do logout :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nama_art'     => 'required',
        'foto_art'     => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg',
        'tahun_awal'   => 'required',
        'deskripsi_art'   => 'required',
        'tautan_art'   => 'required',
        'nama_tautan_art'   => 'required'
    ]);

    //upload image
    $foto_art = $request->file('foto_art');
    $foto_art->storeAs('public/web-template/img/gallery', $foto_art->hashName());

    $artMovement = ArtMovement::create([
        'nama_art'     => $request->nama_art,
        'foto_art'     => $foto_art->hashName(),
        'tahun_awal'   => $request->tahun_awal,
        'deskripsi_art'   => $request->deskripsi_art,
        'tautan_art'   => $request->tautan_art,
        'nama_tautan_art'   => $request->nama_tautan_art
    ]);

    if($artMovement){
        //redirect with success message
        return redirect()->route('/backend/blog')->with(['message' => 'Data Berhasil Disimpan!']);
    }else{
        //redirect with error message
        return redirect()->route('/backend/blog')->with(['message' => 'Data Gagal Disimpan!']);
    }
}
```

**And here's the route :**

```
Route::resource('/', BeritaController::class);
Route::get('tampil', [BeritaController::class, 'artMovement']);
Route::get('asset', [BeritaController::class, 'asset']);
Route::get('partner', [BeritaController::class, 'partner']);
Route::get('event', [BeritaController::class, 'event']);

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});

Route::get('/logout', function()
{
    auth()->logout();
    session()->flush();
    return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'level:admin']], function(){
    Route::get('/backend/blog', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'index'])->name('blogindex');
    Route::get('/backend/create', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'create'])->name('blogcreate');
    Route::get('/backend/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'edit'])->name('blogedit');
    Route::get('/backend/delete/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'destroy'])->name('blogdelete');
    Route::post('/backend/store', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'store'])->name('blogstore');
    Route::put('/backend/update/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'update'])->name('blogupdate');
    Route::get('/search', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::class, 'search']);
    
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\HomeController::class, 'backend'])->name('home');
});
```

Comment: Is it actually logging you out, or were you not logged in properly in the first place?

Comment: its logging me out

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Inspect the request in your browser's devtools - is it really POSTing to the URI it should? Is the data from the form sent correctly? What is the server response? Are you really sure you are logged in at the time you post the form?

Answer (score 0):

1. **First possible solution:**

   check if you properly logged in because you use the auth middlware, this
   middlware will redirect you to login page if you are not logged in.
2. **The second possible solution**

   check the session lifetime in **config/session.php**
3. **third possible solution**

   check if your csrf token work properly try to disable it in **'/backend/store'**
   route

I hope this work for you!